# Camera application in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to iOS development and I have made a sample application which has a

```
UIImageView and UIButton
```

on the click of the button I allow the user to take a picture from the device camera,

After taking the picture I get two options use photo or retake,

I also want to allow the user to rotate and crop the image, I have set

```
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

But it does not help me with anything,
How can I incorporate such functionality in my app.

This is my code snippet on press of the button presently,

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: I want to implement something like the WhatsApp camera that allows you take a picture and once taken gives you an option to rotate or resize.

Comment: I suggest you to go with your own image edit view controller. Allow editing property wont let you to rotate the image. You can do image scaling and cropping based on your need and no rotate function there. So Its good to have another view controller will will allow user to do all these three functions.

Comment: I am new to iOS development can you suggest some sample tutorials form where I can learn ?

Comment: Which language u prefer. Objective C or Swift??

if you are looking for a Swift, the below link may work for you. This will cover all fundamentals of Swift language 
https://it-ebooks.org/book/oreilly/ios_9_programming_fundamentals_with_swift

Comment: Objective C but I am not in search of books looking forward for some practical tutorial